# Load entire live system into RAM?

Tags: linux-mint, boot, live-usb, livecd, parted-magic

If I boot Linux without installation  (i.e. from live DVD), how can I load the entire disc into RAM in order to be able to re-use the drive?

It is possible with PartedMagic already. **How can I do it with Linux Mint?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the boot option `toram`.

For details see -

- [Re: Loading persistent USB Flash to RAM](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=264548#p1435390) - answer on Linux Mint forum.
- [casper - a hook for initramfs-tools to boot live systems](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man7/casper.7.html) - Ubuntu manpages.